# I can't load my website on iPage. How could I do?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-hosting

I upload my websites on iPage.
When I visit my website address, then there would be seen as home.html.
Only "This site is under development", I could seen.
I tried to edit .htaccess file and change URL Redirect, Default Pages, and so on.
But never my page was loaded.
What's the matter?
I can't know the reason. Thanks for reading my problem.

Comment: Can you please remove their home.html an create your custom index.html/index.php/home.html/home.php and let as know if something changes?

Comment: Thank for your repsonse.

That way I did. But in that case only index.html/index.php... could be loaded. For example my project folder is '/test'. Then I make a call as 'http://mytest.com/test'. But there would be blank page. What's the matter? For 3 days, because of this problem I did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

remove their `home.html` and create your custom `index.html` / `index.php` / `home.html` / `home.php`

Comment: Thank for your repsonse.

That way I did. But in that case only index.html/index.php... could be loaded. For example my project folder is '/test'. Then I make a call as 'http://mytest.com/test'. But there would be blank page. What's the matter? For 3 days, because of this problem I did nothing.

Comment: You need a friendly url redirect in your .htaccess can you please show us your .htaccess file? Also, it can be your index page has an error. In case your index is php please check your error log.

Comment: On my local server(xampp), my index php well done. But on iPage it doesn't works. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Test is a page or a directory?

Comment: Just I discovered one thing. iPage PHP hosting version is 5.3.

Comment: you can downgrade it to 5.2 and 4 but you can not upgrade it. :(  In case you want to know how, go to 
CGI and Scripted Language Support > PHP Scripting  > Select Default PHP Version Dropdown

Comment: That way I know, but I worked on PHP 5.4 for a long time. And now my project is so big. Downgrade is too difficult. In this case, as your response,  what would u do?

Comment: Mmmm to be honest with you, I only use iPage for showing some mockups or as a "virtual storage" if this is a production environment, I usually use VPS (virtual private server) so I can fully control my environment. You can always call iPage, and ask them when they will update their server. However; for $1/m you know what are you going to get :) Good luck w/ your project.

Comment: Many thanks for your responses. You are great!!!!! Further more, could we share informations? Then how?

Comment: You can always write your information in your profile, I can contact you. It is not recommended to put any information in comments. Please do not forget to mark the question as answered.  :)